# Как последовательно выполнить функции из get обращения?

Tags: node.js, express

```
var pndli = [];
app.get('/',(request,response)=>{
  pndlist.findAll({raw: true}).then(pndlist=>{
    pndli = pndlist;
  }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
  response.render('index',{
    arr: pndli
  });
  console.log(pndli);
});
```

Нужно что бы массив сначала перезаписывался, а потом уже выполнялся рендер и вывод в консоль. Сейчас как я понимаю он сначала все выводит, а потом запрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
let pndli = [];

app.get('/', (request, response) => {

  pndlist.findAll({ raw: true })
  .then(arr => {
    pndli = arr;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    response.render('index', { arr: pndli });
    console.log(pndli);
  });

});
```

Comment: так мне надо что бы рендерилось невзирая на то будет ошибка или нет

Comment: @ЮраГорячев обновил. В следующий раз сразу уточняйте все нюансы